# 'Link' is declared but its value is never read / React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to make my first project on React, but i am facing some issues with it. My imported **react-router-dom** libraries are not being used on **LINK**.
I do get an error: *'Link' is declared but its value is never read.* Thank you in advance!

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar() {
    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="navbar-container">
                    <LINK to="/" className="navbar-logo">
                        //TRVL <i className='fab fa-typo3'/>
                    </LINK>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: `<Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">` and `</Link>` !?

Comment: Yes, ExacT cAsiNG matTers in React! (and all of javascript)

Comment: Thank you @luk2302 and Peter B for your insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are declaring `Link` in the import statement and then trying to use `LINK` in code. `Link` != `LINK`, the case should match.